# Setting a constant (date) value for class property

Tags: python, class

I use an incremental backup script which stores new/changed data in a date-stamped directory (e.g. 2022-08-24) via rsync. After completing the backup, a symlink is created as a reference for rsync's `--link-dest` parameter during the next backup.

This works reasonably well, unless the backup runs past midnight. In this case, my Backup class' `target_dir` property returns two different values for the actual target dir and the symlink destination because the `datetime.date.today()` method is evaluated
twice:

```
@property
def target_dir(self):
    return f'{self.target_path}/{datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}'
```

I obviously need to set a fixed value for the current date for each run, but I wonder whether this should be a class variable or an instance variable (using `setattr()`). Both methods seem to work fine.

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks,
Jan

Comment: Based on what you are describing, the issue is that the property has different values if you read it at different times. To me this indicates that you want to set this value in your constructor (`__init__`) as a private field (`self._target_dir`) and just refer to it in the property. No need for `setattr`.

Comment: use whatever you like. I would use simple `self.target_dir` without functions, `@property` or `setattr()`

Comment: Thanks! I followed tituszban's advice and added a private attribute to the constructor. The `target_dir` function/property is actually more complex than described above and cannot be reduced to a simple attribute.